# How to Update a column in Tableb from Tablea without using another column as a identity?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have only 1 column(`p_id`) which is common in both tables `Tablea` and `Tableb`.

In `Tablea`, `p_id` values are 101 to 109, and in `Tableb`,`p_id`  values are null.

I need to update `Tableb` `p_id` values from `Tablea` `p_id` values.

How can I do this?

I've run below query but it doesn't work without another identity column:

```
update tableb set pid=(select tablea.pid from tablea) where tableb.id between 1 and 9;
```

and it return the following error message:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 197 Subquery returned more than 1
>   value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= ,>, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. The statement has been terminated.

there is another column `ID` in `Tableb` which contains values from 1 to 9.

Comment: The error says it all, you are trying to set more than `1` value to pid of `tableb`.

Comment: is there a relationship between the tables? if so, please mention it.

Comment: Yes, p_id in tableb is used as a foreign key. And I want to update all values of tablea p_id in tableb p_id

Comment: @JasonClark so randomly selected `p_id` is ok for you, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below

Schema as you said:

```
CREATE TABLE #TABLE_A (PID INT )

INSERT INTO #TABLE_A
SELECT 101 
UNION ALL
SELECT 102
UNION ALL
SELECT 103
UNION ALL
SELECT 104
UNION ALL
SELECT 105
UNION ALL
SELECT 106
UNION ALL
SELECT 107
UNION ALL
SELECT 108
UNION ALL
SELECT 109


CREATE TABLE #TABLE_B (ID INT, PID INT )

INSERT INTO #TABLE_B
SELECT 1, NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 4, NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 5, NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 6, NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 7, NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 8, NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 9, NULL
```

Now update the TABLE_B with below like statement

```
UPDATE #TABLE_B SET #TABLE_B.PID = T_A.PID
FROM (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) SNO , PID FROM #TABLE_A
)AS T_A
INNER JOIN (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) SNO , ID, PID FROM #TABLE_B
)AS T_B ON T_A.SNO = T_B.SNO
WHERE #TABLE_B.ID = T_B.ID
```

**Method 2: But hardcoded**

```
UPDATE #TABLE_B SET #TABLE_B.PID = A.PID
 FROM #TABLE_A A
INNER JOIN #TABLE_B B ON A.PID-100 = B.ID
```

Comment: I have not observed your answer when i give a try. Sorry. @Suraz

Comment: Method 2 is not working however the rows are effected but when checking the status its still null.

Comment: I have also tried this but it updates all values with single value '1'.            update tableb set tableb.pid=tablea.pid from tablea where exists (select tablea.pid from tablea where id between 1 and 7)

Comment: It working fine for above schema data. May be your actual data is differing from the schema I provided. Anyhow method1 will update it without -100 hard coding @JasonClark

Comment: Actually i don't want to update it as per base on tablea.id=tableb.id

Comment: In method 1 I am not doing update based on tablea.id=tableb.id. But doing it based on  tableb.id=tableb.id. Please observe. @JasonClark

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131463/discussion-between-jason-clark-and-shakeer-mirza).

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve that simply from `JOIN`, It will update your `NULL` `pid`s from `tableA`

This solution is data specific and we have to add some value to have a `join` for the solution

```
UPDATE b SET b.pid = a.pid 
FROM tableB b 
INNER JOIN tableA a ON a.pid = b.id+100
WHERE b.pid IS NULL
```

I think `PID` is null for `ID 1 to 9` so in the above code it will check the `NULL` values and update accordingly but if you don't want to update all `NULL` values then you can add condition in the `WHERE` as

```
AND b.id between 1 and 9;
```

**Please try one updated above.**